# Launch Expo GO project locally, not via previous build

Tags: android, react-native, expo, eas

my problem is rather simple / silly but after building my project via Expo's EAS system. I can't launch my project locally anymore, or at least I can't do it. It always launches from the last build on the Expo site.

I'd like to know how to launch my project locally so that I can test it on an emulator (Android Studio) and see the changes in real time. Rather than having to build my project each time it changes (and wait +40min for it to be built).

Answer (score 0):

Without more context i can only give some advise.

Be sure to build in development mode, expo normally always asks after every build to install it on an Emulator. Download the latest build (development mode) and place it on an emulator yourself.

It is supposed to launch from the last build on the expo.dev site because it is the most up to date one. Normally you shouldn't build after every change and it should automatically appear if you have a development build installed of course.

For more information:

- [Expo building modes](https://docs.expo.dev/workflow/development-mode/)